# Intrinsic function to convert integers to real(16)

Tags: fortran

What is the best way to convert an integer to a quadruple precision number?

For double precision I use

```
StrainStep = MaximumStrain/dble(StrainIterations)
```

but now `StrainStep` and `MaximumStrain` are `real(16)`.  What do I use instead of `dble`?

Comment: Note that the quadruple precision does not have to be `real(16)` in every compiler, it can easily be some other kind number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StrainStep = MaximumStrain/real(StrainIterations, 16)`